# A que se debe el error Execution Timed Out (12000 ms) en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy practicando en CodeWars un código para encontrar un numero que aparezca una cantidad impar de veces. Estoy usando un bucle while en mis intentos por encontrar una solución y aunque una de las pruebas parece estar pasando, debajo obtengo el error "Execution time out (12000 ms)
Estoy intentando este código. Pero no sé si el error tiene que ver con código o con la plataforma. Leí que a otros les ha pasado lo mismo tambien.

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  var number=0;
  var counter=0;
  var i=0;
  
  number= A[i];
 
  while(i<A.length){
    if(A[i]==number){
      counter++;
    }else{
      continue
    }
    i++;
  }
  
  if(counter%2!=0){
    return 'El numero '+number+' aparece '+ counter +'veces';
  }
}
```

"

Answer (score 0):

te comento, cuando vos pones ese continue, no estas incrementando el contador, entonces siempre estas verificando el mismo numero del array, lo que te lleva a que sea siempre false, y por ende continue sin incrementar el contador.

Simplemente deberías incrementar el contador antes del continue para pasar al siguiente valor

```
function findOdd(A) {
  var number=0;
  var counter=0;
  var i=0;
  
  number= A[i];
 
  while(i<A.length){
    if(A[i]==number){
      counter++;
    }else{
      i++; //Incrementamos aquí también para que no generar un loop
      continue
    }
    i++;
  }
  
  if(counter%2!=0){
    return 'El numero '+number+' aparece '+ counter +'veces';
  }
}
```

Espero haber ayudado!